# How to get the URL an Android app is hitting?

Tags: android, android-networking

I want to know if there's any way to find out the URL when any android app makes a network request.

Like, for websites,  when we use Chrome Developer tools we can find out the URL of the ajax request made by the webpage of any website.

Is there any such way for Android app?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use charles as a proxy server on your computer. Open your mobile phone network setting and set the http proxy and then you can grab request from you android app. Charles download url https://www.charlesproxy.com/。
2. Open WIFI wireless hotspot on your computer then connect to the hotspot。Now you can use wireshark or httpScoop to grab request from you android app.